# Add values in one column and return the sum on one row

Tags: python, pandas

Current output:

```
df= df.loc[df['Week_Date'] == '2342',['Week_Date','Revenue']]
```

| Week_Date | Revenue |
| --- | --- |
| 2342 | 7.0 |
| 2342 | 8.0 |
| 2342 | 6.0 |
| 2342 | 9.0 |
| 2342 | 9.0 |
| 2342 | 4.0 |
| 2342 | 8.0 |
| 2342 | 4.0 |

I have tried .sum() but this only returns 55. I want it in a row in the df.

```
df= df.loc[df['Week_Date'] == '2342',['Week_Date','Revenue']].sum()
```

Goal - one single row with the sum of all Revenue when Week_Date == 2342:

| Week_Date | Revenue |
| --- | --- |
| 2342 | 55.0 |

Comment: Try: `df.loc[df['Week_Date'] == '2342', ['Week_Date', 'Revenue']].agg({'Week_Date': lambda x: x.iloc[0], 'Revenue': 'sum'}).to_frame().T`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group on week_date, then sum

```
df2 = df.groupby('Week_Date')['Revenue'].sum().reset_index()
```

which gives:

```
   Week_Date   Revenue
0        2342     55.0
```

Comment: Prefer, `df.groupby('Week_Date', as_index=False)['Revenue'].sum()`

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you can use `groupby` but you can also chain with `agg`:

```
out = (df.loc[df['Week_Date'] == '2342', ['Week_Date', 'Revenue']]
         .agg({'Week_Date': lambda x: x.iloc[0], 'Revenue': 'sum'})
         .to_frame().T)
print(out)

# Output
  Week_Date Revenue
0      2342    55.0
```

Comment: Using `lambda x: x.iloc[0]` in the `agg` expression results in `ValueError: cannot perform both aggregation and transformation operations simultaneously`

Comment: @user19077881. `x.iloc[0]` returns a single value, `sum` also returns a single one so all operations in `agg` have to return a unique value. What are you other operations?